# Difference between requestMatchers().mvcMatchers( and mvcMatcher(

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I know that requestMatchers specifies to which requests the security check applies but there is also mvcMatcher which is pretty similar. Can they be used interchangeably?

e.g.

```
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) 
      httpSecurity.requestMatchers().mvcMatchers("/*")...
```

vs

```
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) 
      httpSecurity.mvcMatcher("/*")...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no big difference between those two methods. When you have a simple configuration with a single path, you can use `mvcMatcher("/api/**")` for example.

When a more advanced configuration is necessary, you can use `requestMatchers(...)` or `requestMatcher(...)`, like so:

```java
http
    .requestMatchers()
        .mvcMatchers("/api/**")
        .mvcMatchers("/admin/**")
        .requestMatchers(myCustomRequestMatcher())
```

If you look at the source code, the `mvcMatchers()` method call the `requestMatcher()` method:

```java
public HttpSecurity mvcMatcher(String mvcPattern) {
    HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector = new HandlerMappingIntrospector(getContext());
    return requestMatcher(new MvcRequestMatcher(introspector, mvcPattern));
}
```